# Get Name from characters that died on Episode3 with its killer

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, where-clause

I have a doubt on this sql problem.

[image: mysql]

Here is the tables.

I currenly have all the characters names that died on Episode 3, but I don't know how to get the character killers.

Any idea?

```
Select name from characters c, deaths d where c.id = d.id_character and d.id_film= (Select id from films f where f.episode = "Episode III")
```

This is my sql query so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the characters table twice:

```
select c.name, k.name as killer
from films f
inner join deaths d on f.id = d.id_film
inner join characters c on c.id = d.id_character 
inner join characters k on k.id = d.id_killer
where f.episode = 'Episode III'
```

Notes:

- Use standard joins! Implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause) are legacy syntax from (literaly) decades ago, that should not be used in new code
- Use single quotes for literal strings; in standard SQL, double quotes stand for identifiers (although MySQL makes things differently)

Comment: Wow thanks! It works but I don't know how, many thanks I will investigate this!